# Using FFmpeg to convert to AC3 and remove extra audio tracks

Tags: ffmpeg

Since I have a TV that only supports AC3 (Dolby Digital) files, I’m having to convert most movies. Right now I’m following a tutorial that provide me this code:

```
ffmpeg -i FILENAME.mkv -map 0 -vcodec copy -scodec copy -acodec ac3 -b:a 640k FILENAME-AC3.mkv
```

I want to know if is possible to remove all audio tracks except the main one, and then start the conversion to AC3. Also if there is a way to do it automaticaly, because right now I’m doing it manually, via command line.

Comment: Is the main track the first audio track?

Comment: Yes, the main track is the first audio track

Comment: Adobe products like Premiere Pro don't support DTS so I had the same question to convert DTS to AC3.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the main audio is the first track, use

```
ffmpeg -i FILE.mkv -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:s -c copy -c:a ac3 -b:a 640k FILE-AC3.mkv
```

Comment: Got it. But if the audio track is third, for example? What should I change? And I see you removed `-vcodec copy -scodec copy -acodec ac3`. Can you tell me why?

Comment: `-c copy -c:a ac3` is a shorter way to express the same options. `-c` sets codec for all streams and `-c:a` overrides that for audio.  If main audio is 3rd audio stream, then use `-map 0:a:2`. (ffmpeg starts count from zero).

Comment: Worked flawlessly, thanks a lot. One last question. If the original track is 7.1 or 5.1 DTS and I remove the code `-b:a 640k` the results will be the same?

Comment: No. ffmpeg's AC-3 encoder will pick a bitrate based on channel count.

Comment: It should be `-c:v copy`. (right?)

Comment: @Shayan `-c` means "codec", `:v` means "only video" and `copy` means "leave codec untouched". If you set `-c copy` it means "copy all selected streams and leave all codecs untouched". I'm not sure what happens if you reduce `-c copy` to `:v`, but I think this removes all other audio tracks as only `0:a:0` has been selected. I'm not sure what happens with the selected subtitles through `0:s`. Maybe returning an error?