# FFmpeg copy multiple stream and one audio stream convert to ac3

Tags: ffmpeg

I have file 1.mkv, which contains the following streams:

- 0 - video
- 1 - audio FR - AC3
- 2 - audio GER - AC3
- 3 - audio EN - DTS
- 4 - subtitles FR
- 5 - subtitles GER
- 6 - subtitles GER
- 7 - subtitles GER
- 8 - subtitles EN

And I would like the resulting file to contain the following streams (order doesn't matter):

- 0 - video
- 2 - audio GER - AC3
- 3 - audio EN - AC3
- 5 - subtitles GER
- 6 - subtitles GER
- 7 - subtitles GER
- 8 - subtitles EN

(delete streams 2 and 4, and convert stream 3 from DTS to AC3)

The only thing I managed to do was either convert all audio streams to AC3 or delete streams 2 and 4. I can't achieve both in one code, no matter how hard I try. Thank you.

Comment: Use [stream mapping](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) and [Stream Specifiers](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers-1). Your question resembles the following [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1827260/cant-work-out-why-i-am-getting-invalid-stream-specifier-0a0-error-in-ffmpeg). And probably few other posts.

Comment: This one also similar topic: https://superuser.com/questions/1279589/using-ffmpeg-to-convert-to-ac3-and-remove-extra-audio-tracks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not tested since I don't have access to such a file right now, but I guess it would be something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -map -0:a:0 -map -0:s:0 -c copy -c:a:1 ac3 output.mkv
```

-map 0: map everyting

-map -0:a:0: remove first audio (french)

-map -0:s:0: remove first subtitle (french)

-c copy: use same codec as original for everything

-c:a:1 ac3: convert second audio (english) to ac3

Comment: It's probably not going to work. There is a warning message: "Multiple -c, -codec, -acodec, -vcodec, -scodec or -dcodec options specified for stream 1, only the last option '-c:a ac3' will be used.".

Comment: You right, it converts all remaing audio streams to ac3, but I guess I have the solution already, check for the updated answer.

Comment: As just for testing you could just convert like 20 seconds of the video with ffmpeg -t 20 -i input.mkv and then use ffprobe to check if the audio was converted....

Comment: It works. Thank you.

Comment: @RicardoBohner I don't have the input file for testing. I guess it's working, but I am not sure why.